# Property which can be null or undefined causing "does not exist" error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to destructure a returned object.

Here is the TypeScript code:

```
const id = 1;
const { film: { title, director } } = await getEvent({ id });
```

I get an error under both `title` and `director`:
`Property does not exist on type film`.
When I hover over `film`, it shows the type:

```
(property) film?: {
    title?: string | null | undefined;
    director?: string | null | undefined;
    ... and 10 more ...;
} | undefined
```

How can I tell the compiler that these properties do exist without changing the type of `title` and `director` to not be undefined/null/optional?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `getEvent`? The problem is probably that you declared `film` as an optional property of the promise value, and typescript is rightfully complaining about it.

Comment: The "correct" solution would most likely be: `const {film} = await getEvent({id})` `if (!film) throw new Error("horrible!")` `const {title, director} = film;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the TypeScript compiler happy by supplying default values:

```
const { film: { title = '', director = '' } = {} } = await getEvent({ id });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const film: { 
              title: string | null | undefined,
              director: string | null | undefined 
             } = await getEvent({ id });
```

Your variable when declared, should have a **name (film)** and then it follows the type of the variable after `:`

Comment: Slight issue, you are not extracting the `film`. it should probably be `const { film: {...}} = await getEvent({ id });`, no?